# Is this usage of "to" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I was writing this sentence:

> This is the id of the project to which the user is added to.

Pardon the technical jargon, I tried to convert the same sentence to something like this:

> This is the drum to which this rum is going to be added to.

I can't put my finger on it but something seems odd about these sentences. Are these sentences really grammatically correct?

Comment: You can lose the final "to" in both sentences.

Comment: @KillingTime oh okay. The second "to" just rolls of the tongue better. Is there a rule that I can look up about this? I wanna read a little more about this.

Comment: The rule is *don't double up the preposition*. It's got to be either *This is the id of the project **to** which the user is added* OR *This is the id of the project which the user is added **to**.* Take your pick.

Comment: Blame it all on the passive voice that introduces such complications. Simpler: *We added the user to this project ID*.

Comment: "The user will be added to the project with this id." This may depend on exactly how you introduce the id earlier. In general, if you're wrestling with a sentence, try reversing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is the id of the project to which the user is added to.

It is wrong (and sounds uneducated) because of the repeated "to".

---

You can say either of the following:

*This is the id of the project to which the user is added.*

or

*This is the id of the project (that) the user is added to.*

I prefer the first version, especially if this is formal documentation.